# SQLServer 2016 SP1 connection error with Server\Instance name via .Net

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity

After SQLServer 2016SP1 installation, installation of ODBC Driver 13.1 resolves problem to start SQLAgent and to read Errorlog in SSMS.

However, another connection exists for .NET connection.
The following connection string does not work :

```
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection

  $Connection.ConnectionString = "server=SERVER\INSTANCE;Database=master;..."

  $Connection.Open()

  Connection.close()
```

The error message is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. ...

What is a solution or workaround to this issue?

Comment: If you're getting the "network-related or instance-specific" error message, we're not going to entertain the question again. It's been asked [over 100 times here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+network-related+instance-specific) and [**over 2,000 times**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+network-related+instance-specific) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello; existing discussions do not resolve my pb with SQLServer 20126SP1.

Comment: Hello, my pb is not resolved. Local connection to SQL Server 2016SP1 local instance is OK OR not OK depending of connection string on .net :
$server="Server\Instance"                        # KO
$server="localhost\Instance"                    # KO

Comment: Following connection string are OK :
$server="Server,30305"                           # OK
$server="localhost,30305"                       # OK
$server="127.0.0.1,30305"                      # OK
$server="Server.domain.net,30305"        # OK
$server="127.0.0.1\Instance"                  # OK
$server = "::1\Instance"                           # OK
$server="Server.domain.net\Instance"    # OK

Comment: existing exchanges on DBAStackExchange website don't contain solution to this probem .... ? Firewall was desactivated, IPv6 was desactivated without sucess :-('

Comment: Please don't litter the site with more duplicates of the same question. If you can find some way to explain why the existing 100+ answers haven't helped you, please update **this** question and it will be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 0):

An actual error would be helpful.

Do your basic troubleshooting as you would any other issue.  If the .Net app is on a different server, try to telnet from the APP server to the DB server using the SQL port. ( Default is 1433 ).  If you get good communication, then it is not a network or firewall issue.

My next recommendation would be add the SQL port to your connection string.  If that doesn't work, check security to make sure the app account has permission to both the SQL box, but also the database.